# Data Toggle text in both direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, jsfiddle, jquery-data

I am trying to toggle the text "Show more" and Show Less" with data, my script is almost working but i need it not stopping once it turns into the text "Show Less" and keep it continuing toggling "Show More" and "Show Less".  What i am missing in my function ?

Here my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/3Ndcg/1/

```
<div class ="scorer_filter">
 <a href="#" class="hide_full_list" data-less="Show Less" data-more="Show More" data-table-id="32301" id="toggle">Show More</a>
</div>

  $(function() {
  $(".scorer_filter").on("click", ".hide_full_list", function(){
  var txt = "Show More" ? $('#toggle').data("less") : $('#toggle').data("more");
  $('#toggle').text(txt);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not testing the "txt" variable in your code. You should have done:

```
var txt = $('#toggle').text();
txt = (txt == "Show More") ? $('#toggle').data("less") : $('#toggle').data("more");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ndcg/2/

Answer (score 1):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/d62cQ/):

```
  $(function() {
    $(".scorer_filter").on("click", ".hide_full_list", function(){
      var txt = $(this).text() == "Show More" ? $(this).data("less") : $(this).data("more");
      $(this).text(txt);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`var txt = "Show More" ? $('#toggle').data("less") : $('#toggle').data("more");`

is broken, it'll always put "Show More" in txt.  Try something like this instead:

```
   $(function() {
        $(".scorer_filter").on("click", ".hide_full_list", function(){
            if ($('#toggle').data("less")) {
                $('#toggle').data("less",false).text("Show less");
            } else {
                $('#toggle').data("less",true).text("Show more");
            }
        });
    });
```